# R (linear regression) two coefficients for one variable possible?

Tags: r, regression

I want to estimate the following equation in R:

```
W=(1-p)*(α*X + β*Y) + p*Z+ϵ
```

It has two coefficients for the variables `X` and `Y`, namely `(1-p)` and `α` resp. `(1-p)` and `β`.

What I have tried so far is: `lm(W~(X+Y)+Z)`, trying to indicate with the brackets () that `X+Y` is an additional block. This is wrong. Unfortunately, `R` believes the equation is:

```
W=α*X+β*Y+p*Z+ϵ
```

How can I use a second coefficient in the regression?

Comment: I think this is a statistical question, so I have voted to move it to CrossValidated.

Comment: This is a question of algebraically rewriting the coefficients. `p` is the coefficient of `Z` that you get from `lm()`. Now you divide the coefficients you get for `X` and `Y` by `(1-p)` to get `\alpha` and `\beta`. But there are NOT two coefficients for `X` and `Y`. As a whole, You have three variables (`X`, `Y`, `Z`) and three coefficients (`p`, `\alpha`, `\beta`).`

Answer (score 3):

Perform the regression and calculate the transformed values:

```
fm <- lm(W ~ X + Y + Z + 0)

rho <- coef(fm)[3]
alpha <- coef(fm)[1] / (1-rho)
beta  <- coef(fm)[2] / (1-rho)
```

Alternately,

```
nls(W ~ (1-rho) * (alpha * X + beta * Y) + rho * Z, start = ...whatever...)
```

Also the question did not mention constraints on the coefficients but if there are such, e.g. rho is in [0,1] and others >= 0 then `nls` does allow upper and lower bounds to be specified.

Please read `?nls` carefullly if you want to take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

For R to interpret `X+Y` as a single variable you should use R's Inhibit Interpretation/Conversion of Objects function, `I(x)`

So your linear regression would be

`lm(W~I(X+Y)+Z)`

Comment: This will not permit $\alpha$ to differ from $\beta$ and therefore does not reflect the intended model.